# Implement find all with Spring and specification-arg-resolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I want to implement find all functionality for Angular with specification-arg-resolver and Spring.

I'm trying to send this Url:

```
[HPM] GET /api/be/find?name=tes&login=tes&allowed_ip_address=tes&page=0&size=10
```

BE implemented with [specification-arg-resolver](https://github.com/tkaczmarzyk/specification-arg-resolver)

```
public Page<BeDTO> getAllBySpecification(
            @And({
                @Spec(path = "name", spec = LikeIgnoreCase.class),
                @Spec(path = "login", spec = LikeIgnoreCase.class),
                @Spec(path = "allowed_ip_address", spec = LikeIgnoreCase.class)
        }) Specification<Be> specification,
        Pageable pageable
    ) {        
        return merchantService.getAllBySpecification(specification, pageable)
```

When I send param for `name` to `login` it's working fine.

But when I send all 3 params to implement `All` search functionality I get nothing. Looks like I need some different spec configuration.

Do you have any idea why it's not working properly?

Into log I get:

```
select * from merchants merchants0_ where (upper(merchants0_.name) like ?) and (upper(merchants0_.login) like ?) and (upper(merchants0_.allowed_ip_address) like ?) limit ?
```

Comment: Did you try rewrite spec with specifying params and path @Spec(path="name.merchants", params="name", spec=LikeIgnoreCase.class) ?

Comment: No, can you show me example please?

Comment: 1. Add your BE entity to question.
2. Try this spec: @And({
                @Spec(path = "name", params="name", spec = LikeIgnoreCase.class),
                @Spec(path = "login", params="login", spec = LikeIgnoreCase.class),
                @Spec(path = "allowed_ip_address", params="allowed_ip_address", spec = LikeIgnoreCase.class)
        }

Comment: Are you sure there is a corresponding row in the DB? The code looks ok and the generated query is also ok.

Comment: Yes, for single search String it's working fine.

Comment: Which Database are you using? MySQL, PostgreSQL,...

Comment: MariaDB - latest version.

Comment: I agree with @SashaShpota. I'd try to find the reason at the DB level. The query looks fine. I'd double check data types in the DB. Can be that the IP address is stored in binary format and obviously the query wouldn't work in that case.

Comment: I think the upper() functions in the query are unnecessary because LIKE is case-insensitive by default. see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/like/

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of Using Specification class you can pass name,login and ip_address in your HQL query.**

```
public Page<BeDTO> getAllBySpecification(String name,String login,String ip_address,
                Pageable pageable
            ) {        
                return merchantService.getAllBySpecification(name,login,ip_address pageable);
            }

select * from Merchants as merchants where merchants.name like %:name%  and merchants.login like %:login% and merchants.allowed_ip_address like %:allowed_ip_address%
```